# Why in blender when I try to open a specific file it crashes?

Tags: armature, blend-files

If I open any other file and append an armature from the specific file, blender closes immediately, but I can import all the other object from the file.

Comment: What version are u using and what version is the file u opened? maybe u are opening a high version file in low version blender which will usually not work

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the Blender file version is same/below the version of Blender you're currently running.

For example, if you're running Blender 3.5 then you can only open blend files 3.5 and below and not 3.6. You can open an uncompressed blend file in a text editor and it will say on the top line the version of Blender the file was made with.

To be safe just download the most recent version of Blender 3.6.1 to see if it can import what you need. If not it's probably something else. When you save a blend file for the first time the actual file imprints the version of Blender that you first saved it with.